# Where is this score screenshot from?

Tags: game-identification

[image]

The score categories make this look like a rhythm game. Some of the text is in Japanese.

Comment: Please use the google image-search at https://www.google.de/imghp

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the game is [*アイドリッシュセブン*](http://idolish7.com/) which translated to [*IDOLiSH 7*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BB%E3%83%96%E3%83%B3) which looks to be a male orianted Idol Rhythm Game (similar to *Love Live* and *IdolM@ster*)

i belive it's this because a [google reverse image search](https://www.google.com.au/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisch0XKkAfY1G_1Q2doKHaGwFdNW1M6lhpjsEu0VDbiPOQ7SGQDbgXZdeUv2JHoI7-pzbQqjVB8MBrkZ2RPgJocNCzSNgd-qlQ86e8wFz4vi-zhCqTi_1OLG0RpvLV9WRt7oTJw_1i1Kuk9DuiWnRPYiUIPZgyqb9yeiXL9rM3ew6S8iZ_1i39StogrG63vDv_1o0yJn6nd7zdrQdjIDZwDXez1JqY-Ok-Gr-aqPw4F_1NlBK2ijGcoHMEiMIpmn9YCo1R6VXMXohEZsPewSftXZnPkafF4lcH0PbS40AUpgpdRWRr3M1gpFFjWImrS4oDQlSSrJat-3lojJJH7U8YGl8UOBZgJ23Sg) showed me this

[image: Google Results]

and from that [first link](https://aminoapps.com/c/idolish7/page/blog/data-recover/Kmrr_pXsMupWB7K8Y8znml2V2EB3Zl40a), while it did not have the image shown did have [this post](https://aminoapps.com/c/idolish7/page/blog/thank-you-for-everything-idolish7/jVJJ_aRUKu30klN3EqxvJx11RG7Rz0Pzl4) which did have the image

[image: Screenshot]

as we can see, very similar UI and the post it came from ait titled

> Thank You For Everything {IDOLiSH7}

Answer (score 6):

Looks like it's [IDOLISH 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idolish7).

At least google search yields very similar results for it : [Idolish 7 score game](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS790US790&biw=2560&bih=1366&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=oWHeWvO0DILR0gKX6J6AAw&q=idolish%207%20score%20game&oq=idolish%207%20score%20game&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9139.9694.0.9935.6.6.0.0.0.0.110.489.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.147...0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.kMSvkedJeLA)